# Show independence of number of heads and tails

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am independently studying Larry Wasserman's "All of Statistics"

Chapter 2 exercise 11 is this:

Let $N \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and suppose we toss a coin $N$ times. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the number of heads and tails. Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

First, I don't understand what the significance of the Poisson distribution of $N$ is?

Secondly, I am guessing that I'm supposed to show:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$$

I know that:

$f_X(x) = {n \choose x} p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$ because the number of heads would follow a binomial distribution

I don't understand how to express $f_Y(y)$ or $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$

Comment: The significance of the Poisson distribution of $N$ is that most other distributions would not lead to independence of $X$ and $Y$, with the most obvious example being where $N$ is a positive constant $n$ in which case $X$ and $Y$ would determine each other

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **conditional** distribution of $X$ given the event $N=n$ is the particular binomial distribution that you identify.  But notice that the support of the marginal (i.e. not conditional on $N$) distribution of the number of heads is $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$. It doesn't just go up to some number $n$ and then stop. It is unbounded: there is no integer so large that the probability that that is the number of heads is $0$.  Hence the marginal (unconditional) distribution of $X$ cannot be a binomial distribution.  Nor $Y$, for the same reason.  Notice that the conditional expectation of $X$ given $N$ is $pN$, so the marginal (unconditional) expectation of $X$ is $p\,\operatorname{E}N = p\lambda$, and that of $Y$ is $(1-p)\lambda$.

We have
$$
\Pr(X=x\mid N) = \binom N x p^x(1-p)^{N-x},
$$
so
\begin{align}
& \Pr(X=x) = \operatorname{E}(\Pr(X=x\mid N)) = \operatorname{E}\left(\binom N x p^x(1-p)^{N-x} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \sum_{n=x}^\infty \binom n x p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\cdot\Pr(N=n) \\[10pt]
= {} & \sum_{n=x}^\infty \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!} p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\cdot\frac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda}}{n!} \tag a\\[10pt] 
= {} & \sum_{n=x}^\infty \underbrace{\frac{(p\lambda)^x e^{-p\lambda}}{x!}}\cdot\frac{((1-p)\lambda )^{n-x} e^{-(1-p)\lambda}}{(n-x)!}. \tag b
\end{align}
Now a crucial fact is needed: The part over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ does not depend on $n$, so it can be pulled out:
$$
\frac{(p\lambda)^x e^{-p\lambda}}{x!} \sum_{n=x}^\infty \frac{((1-p)\lambda)^{n-x}e^{-(1-p)\lambda}}{(n-x)!}.
$$
This sum is $1$ since it's the sum of probabilities assigned by a certain discrete probability distribution: the Poisson distribution with expected value $(1-p)\lambda$.  Thus we have
$$
\Pr(X=x) = \frac{(p\lambda)^xe^{-p\lambda}}{x!}\cdot1.
$$
In other words $X\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(p\lambda)$.  In the same way, one can show that $Y\sim\mathrm{Poisson}((1-p)\lambda)$.

Now let us think about $\Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y)$ and see if it's the same as $\Pr(X=x)\cdot\Pr(Y=y)$.
\begin{align}
\Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y) & = \operatorname{E}(\Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y\mid N)) \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \underbrace{\Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y\mid N=n)}\cdot\Pr(N=n).
\end{align}
Now the part over the underbrace is $0$ except when $n=x+y$, so the whole sum is just one of the terms:
$$
\Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y) = \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y\mid N=x+y)\Pr(N=x+y).
$$
Now notice that this is exactly the same as
$$
\Pr(X=x\mid N=x+y)\Pr(N=x+y). \tag 1
$$
(In other words $X$ and $Y$ are very very far from independent when one conditions on $N=n$ --- so far from independent that knowing $X$ tells you $Y$.)

Since $X\mid (N=x+y)\sim\mathrm{Binomial}(x+y,p)$ and $N\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$, the value of $(1)$ is
$$
\binom{x+y}x p^x (1-p)^y \frac{\lambda^{x+y}e^{-\lambda}}{(x+y)!}.
$$
The $(x+y)!$ in the numerator and denominator cancels and this whole thing becomes
$$
\frac{(p\lambda)^x e^{-p\lambda}}{x!} \cdot \frac{((1-p)\lambda)^y e^{-(1-p)\lambda}}{y!} = \Pr(X=x)\Pr(Y=y).
$$

Comment: Michael, thank you for an excellent answer.

Comment: I have one question:

I am unsure how you got from equation (a) to (b) (I edited to add these tags). Specifically, I'm not sure about $p$ becoming $p\lambda$ and also where the $e^{(-1-p)\lambda}$ came from.

I assume $p$ to $p\lambda$ is related to the marginal expectation of $X$

Comment: $(p\lambda)^x ((1-p)\lambda)^{n-x} = p^x(1-p)^{n-x} \lambda^x\lambda^{n-x}$ $=p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\lambda^{x+(n-x)}$ $=p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\lambda^n$ and $e^{-p\lambda} e^{-(1-p)\lambda} = e^{-p\lambda-(1-p)\lambda}$ $=e^{-\lambda(p+(1-p))}$ $=e^{-\lambda\cdot1}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

The problem can also be solved without the use of expectations, which at this point of the book (chapter 2 [1]) are yet to be introduced (they only appear in chapter 3 [1]).

As you correctly identified, we are going to be seeking $f_{X}(x)$, $f_{Y}(y)$ and $f_{X, Y}(x, y)$, to show that $$f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y) = f_{X, Y}(x, y)$$ for all $x$, $y$. Should there be any doubt as to why this is equivalent to showing that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, one can consult theorem 2.30, p. 35 in [1],

From the definition of the probability mass function, $f_X(x) = \Pr(X = x)$, $f_Y(y) = \Pr(Y = y)$ and $f_{X,Y}(x, y) = \Pr(X=x, Y=y)$, so we can focus our attention on finding these three probabilities, to establish:

$$\Pr(X = x)\Pr(Y = y) = \Pr(X=x, Y=y)$$

We are going to rely on a few key tricks:

1. The law of total probability (Theorem 1.16, p. 12 [1]): $$P(B)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\Pr(B \mid A_{i})P(A_{i})$$ where $A_{1}, \ldots A_{k}$ is a partition of the sample space, and $B$ is any event.
2. $\sum_{k=0}^{k=+\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}=e^{x}$, which is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Complex_numbers).
3. $P(X = x, N = n) = \Pr(X = x, Y = n - x)$, which comes from the fact that $X + Y = N$.
4. Not really a trick, but from the definition of conditional probability, $\Pr(A \mid B)\Pr(B) = \Pr(AB)$

Using trick 1 we can write down: $$\Pr(X = x) = \Pr(X = x \mid N < x)\Pr(N < x) + \sum_{k=0}^{k=+\infty}\Pr(X=x \mid N = x + k)\Pr(N = x + k)$$

The first part of the sum is 0, since $N$ can never be less than $x$. Let us compute the second part.

Using the definitions of Binomial and Poisson distributions, we can write the following:

$$\Pr(X=x \mid N = x + k) = {x + k \choose x} p^x(1-p)^k$$

$$\Pr(N=x + k) = e^{-λ} \frac {λ^{x + k}}{(x + k)!}$$

This, after some simplifications, gives us

$$e^{-λ}\frac{λ^x}{x!}p^x\sum_{k = 0}^{k = +\infty}\frac{(λ(1-p))^{k}}{k!}$$

The time has come to apply trick 2, which yields:

$$\Pr(X = x) = p^{x}\frac{λ^{x}}{x!}e^{-λp}$$

By symmetry, we can argue that: $$\Pr(Y = y) = (1-p)^{y}\frac{λ^{y}}{y!}e^{-λ(1-p)}$$

We're half-way done, but the "crux" of the problem lies in the computation of $\Pr(X = x, Y = y)$. We can apply trick 3.

$$\Pr(X = x, Y = n - x) = \Pr(X = x, N = n)$$

To compute the right side, we can use trick 4. The left side is almost what we desire, except we will have to substitute $y = n - x$ on both sides after we're done with all the computations. So

$$\Pr(X = x, Y = n - x) = \Pr(X = x \mid N = n)\Pr(N = n)$$

$$\Pr(X = x, Y = n - x) = \mathrm{Binomial}(n, p)(x)\mathrm{Poisson}(λ)(n)$$

After some computation we get

$$\Pr(X = x, Y = n - x) = \frac{p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}e^{-λ}λ^{x + n-x}}{x!(n-x)!}$$

Applying the substitution, we have

$$\Pr(X = x, Y = y) = \frac{p^{x}(1-p)^{y}e^{-λ}λ^{x + y}}{x!y!}$$

Which, combined with our previous result, gives $\Pr(X = x)\Pr(Y = y) = \Pr(X=x, Y=y)$, as required.

As other answers have pointed out, this is vaguely amusing, since having $N$ fixed makes $X$ and $Y$ as dependent as variables can possibly be: knowing $X$ determines $Y$ exactly, but somehow, someway setting $N \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(λ)$ adds just about enough randomness to $N$ that learning $X$ doesn't tell us anything about $Y$ that we wouldn't have known before we learned $X$ ($X$ and $Y$ are independent).

The bizarre interplay between $\mathrm{Poisson}$ and $\mathrm{Binomial}$ continues, for additional practice see for example a very similar exercise 2.16, p. 45 [1]

[1] Larry Wasserman, All of Statistics, 2004, corrected second printing, ISBN 0-387-40272-1.

Comment: I think this is the intended solution! The only thing I would add is that it might be nicer to think of Trick 3 as $P(X=x, Y=y) = P(X=x, N=x+y) = P(X=x | N=x+y) P(N=x+y) = \binom{x+y}{x} p^x (1-p)^y e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{x+y}}{(x+y)!} = ...$

Comment: Yes, I like it. I'd maybe inject one extra step, $P(X = x, Y = y) = P(X = x, X + Y = x + y) = P(X = x, N = x + y)$, just to keep things really obvious. Feel free to make an edit.

Comment: The only thing to keep in mind is that this notation is unfortunately repeated throughout the post, so there will have to be some refactoring in place! Also, the remaining of your suggestion is just an application of trick 4 ("not really a trick" trick). I like the idea of keeping that separate, just to decrease notational cognitive load.

Comment: Why do we need $$\Pr(X = x \mid N < x)\Pr(N < x)$$  part in $$\Pr(X = x) = \Pr(X = x \mid N < x)\Pr(N < x) + \sum_{k=0}^{k=+\infty}\Pr(X=x \mid N = x + k)\Pr(N = x + k)$$? Also the sum in the law of total probability starts from 1, why do we start counting from 0?