# Poisson Coin Flipping Problem

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution

A problem from *All of Statistics* pg. 45:

> Let $N \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and suppose we toss a coin $N$ times. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the number of heads and tails. Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

If we let $f$ denote the pmf, I know that independence holds iff

$$
f(X = k) = f(X = k | Y = j) = \frac{f(X = k, Y = j)}{Y = j}
$$

I know also that $N \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ implies that

$$
f(X = i) = \frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!}
$$

for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. The problem is that I don't know how in this instance to compute $f(X = k, Y = j)$.

Comment: here is a hint: $X+Y=N$

Comment: This is a duplicate of [another stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951512/show-independence-of-number-of-heads-and-tails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show how to compute the probability that $X=k$ and $Y=j$ that you asked about. This is the probability that $X+Y=k+j$ times the probability that $X=k$ **given** that $X+Y=k+j$. We assume the coin is fair. A similar calculation can be made for unfair coins.

We have 
$$\Pr(X+Y=k+j)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k+j}}{(k+j)!}.$$
Also, 
$$\Pr(X=k\mid X+Y=k+j)=\binom{k+j}{k}(1/2)^{k+j},$$
since the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $N=n$ is binomial.
It follows that
$$\Pr(X=k\cap Y=j)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k+j}}{(k+j)!}\binom{k+j}{k}(1/2)^{k+j}.$$
This simplifies to
$$e^{-\lambda} \frac{1}{k!j!}(\lambda/2)^k(\lambda/2)^j.$$

For the independence calculation, the simplest approach now is to note that the above expression factors as a function of $k$ times a function of $j$.

Comment: How does then one compute $P(X = k) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda} \frac{1}{k!j!} (\lambda / 2)^k (\lambda / 2)^j$?

Comment: You mean the sum from $j=0$ to $\infty$. This is $e^{-\lambda}\frac{1}{k!}(\lambda/2)^k \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda/2)^j}{j!}$. We recognize the inner sum as $e^{\lambda/2}$, because of the familiar power series for $e^x$. So we get $\Pr(X=k)=e^{-\lambda/2}\frac{(\lambda/2)^k}{k!}$.